# Why all output 0

Tags: c++

Why is the result I output on the [oj website](http://oj.ytu.edu.cn/problem.php?id=3749) all `0`? `Ans` defines global variables, and all the values ​​output on Oj are global variables, and the global variables have not changed. But the test samples are output on the local compiler The example can output the correct result.
code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<cstring> 
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
int n,k,ans=0;
char g[100][100];
bool flagx[100],flagy[100];
//int dirx[4]={-1,0,1,0};//上右下左； 
//int diry[4]={0,1,0,-1}; 
void dfs(int x,int y,int use)
{
    if(use==k)
    {
        ans++;
        return ;
    }
    if(y==n) y=0,x++;
    if(x==n)
    return;
        //不放
        dfs(x,y+1,use); 
        //放 
        if(x>=0&&x<n&&y>=0&&y<n&&g[x][y]=='#'&&!flagx[x]&&!flagy[y])
        {
            flagx[x]=true;
            flagy[y]=true;//标记该位置已经放过棋子;
            dfs(x,y+1,use+1);
            flagx[x]=false;
            flagy[y]=false; 
        }
    //}
}
int main()
{
    while(scanf("%d %d",&n,&k))
    {
        
        memset(flagx,'false',sizeof(flagx));
        memset(flagy,'false',sizeof(flagy));
        //memset(g,'')
        if(n==-1&&k==-1)
        break;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<n;j++)
            cin>>g[i][j];
            dfs(0,0,0);//x,y,ans;坐标,放置的棋子的个数;
            cout<<ans<<endl;
            ans=0;
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

You can consider this screenshot:
[image: Screenshot of the output]

Comment: what is the oj website? What is the input and expected output?

Comment: The oj website of our school, http://oj.ytu.edu.cn/problem.php?id=3749, the expected output is the result, but on the oj test, whatever the input Yang Lie is, the output result is always the beginning The value of the defined global variable.

Comment: `memset(flagx,'false',sizeof(flagx));` will set the whole array to `true`, which may not be what you wanted. Compare `'false'` (which is a non-zero `char`) and `false` (which is a boolean equal to zero).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, [the site of your school](http://oj.ytu.edu.cn/problem.php?id=3749) (which you could include in the question) does not load on my system.

I think that the expected result should depend on the input for `n` and `k` at least. What is the result if you input `n=1, k=0`? I would expect `aws=1` from reading your code.
Notice that in your case, the `dfs` method is exclusively called in the line `dfs(0,0,0)`. I don't know, if that is intended, as the comments are in chinese.